# Any alternative or improvement of my recursive/iterative approach?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, recursion, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to write a parent searching code using python 3.

Parent is a 0-based-array that contain a parent of that element. 
For example, parent=[0,0] means that

1. Parent of the first element is itself.
2. Parent of the second element is the first element, therefore second element 
   value is equal to first element's value

First, I tried using a recursive approach.

```
def getParent2(table):
    # find parent and compress path
    if table!=parent[table]:
        parent[table]=getParent2(parent[table])
    return parent[table]
```

Even though this approach seems to shows a very good speed, it faced a stack-overflow problem in a very large parent array.

(*Setting recursionlimit also resulted in a system error code 7.)

I tried modified it in to iterative approach

```
def getParent3(table):

    while table!=parent[table]:
        table=parent[table]    

    return table
```

Unfortunately it's running unacceptably slow on the same large parent array.

Any ideas to improve this code without changing the recursionlimit?

Thank you.

---

Sorry for not having a sample data, it's a really a large one (10000+) so here is a small sample of this function.

For example,

```
parent=[0,0,2,1,2]
```

`getParent(3)` will gives `0` as a result

Since parent of the 4th element (0-base) is the 2nd element, and the parent of the 2nd element is 1st element

It goes like this, 3-->1-->0

Comment: The issue here is that your original code updates the list as it goes, which caches the intermediate results. Your new code doesn't modify the list, hence it has to re-compute the path repeatedly. However, I'm not certain how to fix this without essentially just using another list as a stack, because you would need to keep track of the cells of parent that need to be updated.

Comment: Great ideat Cel, I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Just to help you finding additional resources if needed: what you are implementin here is called the `find`-operation of a union-find data structure. Updating the parent relation during the find operation is usually called "path compression".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't give us any data to test it on, so I'm assuming @Cel Skeggs identified the key difference in her comment.  Fleshing out her suggestion (but untested because - again - you supplied no data):

```
def getParent4(table):
    chain = []
    while table != parent[table]:
        chain.append(table)
        table = parent[table]    
    for link in chain:
        parent[link] = table
    return table
```

But the speed difference you saw doesn't really make sense unless you're calling the function multiple times at the top level - in which case, collapsing paths can make a huge difference.  However, you didn't say anything about that either ;-)

Comment: Sorry for that, I did post an example on my reply.

Thank you Tim.

Comment: That's fine.  Did the reply help?  If possible, you should accept an answer if it works, or explain what the remaining problems are.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I just finished testing it.

The code provided an accurate answer.

Unfortunately, it's still slower than the first recursive approach and can't make it by the time constraint.

But yeah, I think I will try to modify it a bit.

Comment: @TimPeters: "identified the key difference in _her_ comment."

Comment: My apologies, Cel!  Since I can't abide "zir", I'll switch it to "their".

Comment: @TimPeters while "their" would be a great solution were I nonbinary or if you didn't know the correct pronouns for me, I'm actually female, and would prefer "her". :) (I'd fix it myself, but I'm under 1k rep and would need to send it through the suggested edits queue.)

Comment: Done!  That was too easy :-)

Comment: Instead of storing the indices of the elements for which the parent has to be changed in `chain`, an alternative approach could be to iterate over the path twice; first without changing the entries, just to find the root, and then a second time (starting again from the queried index) to compress the paths. This could reduce memory usage and maybe even speed it up.

Comment: Thanks matz, I will try that.